# Spark 2.0.0 Standalone PySpark Job Hangs After Completion

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am running a PySpark job on Spark 2.0.0 Standalone. My job completes succesfully (as indicated by the UI and the output file), but the spark context never closes and my job stays live.

I'm using the following spark-submit statement:

```
./bin/spark-submit --master ${sparkmaster} --executor-memory 16g --num-executors 45 --executor-cores 3 --verbose /home/spark_mr1mr2.py
```

Here's the end of my PySpark script:

```
.coalesce(1,shuffle=True).saveAsTextFile("mr2out"+os.environ.get("RUN_NAME")+"/", codec) 
exit()
```

And here are the last log messages:

```
16/12/15 23:11:06 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on 192.168.14.250:33654 in memory (size: 20.1 KB, free: 8.4 GB)
16/12/15 23:11:06 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 0
```

What can I do to get the job to complete successfully and exit cleanly? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the way to gracefully stop spark applications is to call stop() on the SparkContext object. If you're using SparkSession, you can call stop() on that as well since all it does is stop the underlying SparkContext.

So likely sc.stop() or spark.stop() instead of exit() will fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't been able to test this directly yet. I think it's working, but I'll accept the answer when I can confirm it's solved my problem.

Comment: It looks like either raising an exception or call sc.stop() will prevent the job from hanging.